# Issue with compiling Apache Traffic Server on RHEL 4(64bit)

Tags: proxy

Is there any special way to compile Apache traffic server on RHEL4 (64bit)? I am getting the following error:

```
ink_atomic_solaris_i86pc.s:151: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
ink_atomic_solaris_i86pc.s:152: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
ink_atomic_solaris_i86pc.s:163: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
ink_atomic_solaris_i86pc.s:165: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
ink_atomic_solaris_i86pc.s:166: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
ink_atomic_solaris_i86pc.s:179: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
ink_atomic_solaris_i86pc.s:180: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
make[1]: *** [ink_atomic_solaris_i86pc.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/trafficserver/traffic-trunk.svn/libinktomi++'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

It compiles fine on a 32bit Box. The project does have 64bit AMI available, so it means it does compile on 64bit RHEL4. Is there any special compile flags or packages required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this. Traffic Server does not compile under 64bit when gcc < 4.x. So, need to upgrade to GCC 4.x when compiling on/for 64bit machine.